# Stop library from swallowing all exceptions in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, exception, kotlin-coroutines

I'm writing an app in Kotlin that uses a third party library which does some asynchronous work, and then passes the result back to my code in a callback. The problem is that the library wraps the callback in a generic try-catch block so any exceptions my code then throws is swallowed by the library.

Is there a way to catch my exceptions without changing to a different thread? I've tried wrapping my code in a `runBlocking` and a `withContext` but exceptions are still caught by the library

Answer (score 1):

You should try to handle exceptions yourself in the code block which is passed to the library, then you can return them as a callback result.

Something like this:

```
fun <T> libraryCall(block: () -> Result<T>): Result<T> {
    TODO()
}

sealed class Result<out T> {
    class Data<T>(val data: T) : Result<T>()
    class Error(val ex: Exception) : Result<Nothing>()
}

fun main() {
    val result = libraryCall {
        return@libraryCall try {
            Result.Data(5)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Result.Error(e)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I found is to use a [CoroutineExceptionHandler](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines/exception-handling.html#coroutineexceptionhandler).

```
val handler = CoroutineExceptionHandler { _, exception ->
  // This will crash the app rather than have the library swallow it
  throw exception
}

// Callback on some thread
GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
  GlobalScope.launch(handler) {
    throw RuntimeException("My code has thrown an exception")
  }.join()
}
```